# What is upgrade spending and more importantly, why does it decrease?

Tags: starcraft-2

At the score screen, under graphs tab, what exactly is upgrade spending? Well it sounds obvious but why does it decrease sometimes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upgrade spending tracks your tech in general, not just "upgrades". So if you build a roach warren, it will show in this graph. If you then lose the roach warren, the graph will reflect this loss in tech.